# why does this code not work in real environment? saying 'normal' is undefined (new coder)

Tags: python, python-2.x

my question: I can get this to work in codeskulptor but not any of my IDE. Please help!

```
Uinput = input("first morph")
Uinput2 = input("second morph")

#this section of code accepts normal or recessive to
#calculate if you will get hets. If hets, clarify morph in separate function
#input to compare are words

def normal_recessive():
if Uinput == ("normal") and Uinput2 == ("normal"):
    print("your results will be all wildtypes")
elif Uinput == ("normal") and Uinput2 == ("recessive"):
    print("Your results will be heterozygous aka hets")
elif Uinput == ("recessive") and Uinput2 == ("normal"):
    print("Your results will be heterozygous aka hets")
elif Uinput == ("recessive") and Uinput2 == ("recessive"):
    print("Your results will be all recessive")
else:
    print("input error, please input recessive or normal for morph type")
    print("please check your spelling and try again")

normal_recessive()
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like CodeSkulptor is running Python 3 and your IDEs are running Python 2. The `input` function behaves differently between the two Pythons.

If you configure your IDEs to use Python 3, your code should work.

Alternatively, the Python 2 `raw_input` function does what the Python 3 `input` function does, so if you need to use Python 2 instead of Python 3, then replace `input` in your code with `raw_input`.

Comment: er, I forgot that I am having issues with python 3x running on my pc as for some reason I can't download or update the api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll no matter who i engage to help me or what I try and do. I'm currently stuck running 2.7, and i was taught 3x X_X  any suggestions?

I've tried updating windows, I've tried downloading the file online, I've tried copying my boyfriends copy of visual studio c++ as that is supposedly where the file comes from....to no avail

Comment: In Python 2, you can use `raw_input` instead of `input`. See the new paragraph I added to my answer. There are a ton of small differences between Python 2 and Python 3, but I don't think any of them are especially difficult to handle.